# Nested write serializer validated_date is empty

Tags: django-rest-framework

Followed the best practive create nested objects with serializers, however I still receive empty nested validate_data.

Serializers:

```
class WriteOrganisationSiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Organisation Site serializer class for post methods."""

    site = WriteAPSiteSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.OrganisationSite
        fields = ("organisation", "site")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        from fadat.sites.models import APSite

        site_data = validated_data.pop("site")
        activeplaces_site_id = site_data.pop("activeplaces_site_id")
        site, created = APSite.objects.get_or_create(
            activeplaces_site_id=activeplaces_site_id, defaults=site_data
        )
        organisation_site = models.OrganisationSite.objects.create(
            site=site, **validated_data
        )

        return organisation_site


class WriteAPSiteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Active Places Site serializer class for post methods."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.APSite
        fields = (
            "activeplaces_site_id",
            "site_name",
            "dependent_thoroughfare",
            "thoroughfare_name",
            "double_dependent_locality",
            "dependent_locality",
            "post_town",
            "postcode",
            "easting",
            "northing",
            "longitude",
            "latitude",
        )
```

The view

```
class OrganisationSitesView(APIView):
    """Organisation Sites API view."""

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = request.user

        ser = serializers.WriteOrganisationSiteSerializer(data=request.data)
        ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        obj = ser.save()

        ser = serializers.ReadOrganisationSiteSerializer(obj)
        return Response(ser.data, status=201)
```

Running the following test (or via browser a ajax request, same result)

```
    def test_add_organisation_site(self):
        user = User.objects.create(email="newbie@dat.example.com")
        organisation_type = OrganisationType.objects.create(name="Club")
        organisation = Organisation.active_objects.create(
            name="Club", organisation_type=organisation_type
        )
        site = {
            "activeplaces_site_id": 1200341,
            "site_name": "CITY OF LONDON SCHOOL",
            "dependent_thoroughfare": "",
            "thoroughfare_name": "QUEEN VICTORIA STREET",
            "double_dependent_locality": "",
            "dependent_locality": "",
            "post_town": "LONDON",
            "postcode": "EC4V 3AL",
            "easting": 531990,
            "northing": 180834,
            "longitude": -0.099387,
            "latitude": 51.511025,
        }
        body = {
            "organisation": organisation.id,
            "site": site,
        }

        self.authenticate(user)

        url = reverse("api:inspections:organisation-sites")
        res = self.client.post(url, json.dumps(body), content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
```

Receiving the following headers in my views

```
{'organisation': 1, 'site': {'activeplaces_site_id': 1200341, 'site_name': 'CITY OF LONDON SCHOOL', 'dependent_thoroughfare': '', 'thoroughfare_name': 'QUEEN VICTORIA STREET', 'double_dependent_locality': '', 'dependent_locality': '', 'post_town': 'LONDON', 'postcode': 'EC4V 3AL', 'easting': 531990, 'northing': 180834, 'longitude': -0.099387, 'latitude': 51.511025}}
```

In the view the `request.data` show me

```
{'Cookie': '', 'Content-Length': '368', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'Token 0081d8a36d90f1d922a2a7df494afe127a220495'}
```

Still the serialized doesn't validate nested fields and returns

```
{'organisation': <Organisation: Club (Club)>, 'site': OrderedDict()}
```

Comment: Could you please share what the ReadOrganisationSiteSerializer looks like in your question? Is it missing a custom `to_representation()`?

Comment: He @ohduran

```class ReadOrganisationSiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Organisation Site serializer class for get methods."""

    organisation = OrganisationSerializer()
    site = APSiteSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.OrganisationSite
        fields = ("id", "organisation", "site")```

Comment: Is the answer below satisfactory @rob-moorman? If it is, it would mean the world if you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Right, here's what I see that needs fixing: the conventional way to design a `post()`method is as follows:

```
 def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    serializer = serializers.WriteOrganisationSiteSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Although your case is in many ways equivalent, it's obviously not 100% correct. Perhaps it has to do with the fact that you're using one serializer to create the new instance, and another to show the result, when that's not needed: you can set up which fields are read_only, which ones are write_only, and those that are both read and write, as [the documentation explains](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments). I suggest you follow the schema I laid out above to guide you, and define in WriteOrganisationSiteSerializer how to show the data to the end user. Do let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This doesn't seem to change a thing (which is obvious, as the problem is not when you read the saved data) as the issues occurs while validating the data:

At the line `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` this nested serialized data for site is an empty ordered dict.

It seems that using a `ModelSerializer` as nested serializeres does something. If I use a default Serializer class (with the same fields, but then written out) is seems to accept validation... strange.